# Difference between Serilog MinimumLevel.ControlledBy and MinimumLevel.Override in web api core?

Tags: logging, overriding, serilog, serilog-exceptions

Can anyone please explain to me what is the difference between Serilog `MinimumLevel.ControlledBy` and `MinimumLevel.Override` in web api core?

Answer (score 1):

`ControlledBy` lets you nominate a Switch variable which will control the logging - this switch can be adjusted (e..g by periodically looking at a global setting)

`Override` lets you provide a value once, that gets frozen into the overall configuration.

The latter provides better performance (though not by a factor that normally matters)